# Dynamically generated HTML not working

Tags: jquery, struts

I am using JQuery to insert HTML in my DIV element
I have the following code in my JSP page

```
<div id="definitionsDiv">
    <s:select id="typeDropdown" list="types" listKey="id" listValue="value" value="3" onchange="getWordList()"/>        
</div>
```

HTML looks like

```
<div id="definitionsDiv">
  <select id="typeDropdown" onchange="getWordList()" name="">
    <option value="1">Adverb</option>
    <option value="2">Adjective</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Noun</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This works fine and displays a dropdown with the values retrieved from the "types" field in my Struts action.
However,  I want to dynamically generate this HTML so I call the following in my doc load method ....

```
function buildDefinitionsHTML()
{
    $("#definitionsDiv").empty();
    $("#definitionsDiv").append('<s:select id="typeDropdown" list="types" listKey="id"     listValue="value" value="1" onchange="getWordList()"/>');
}
```

Now my generated HTML looks like

```
<div id="definitionsDiv">
  <s:select id="typeDropdown" onchange="getWordList()" value="1" listvalue="value"     listkey="id" list="types"></s:select>
</div>
```

It seems there has been no call made back to my action to populate the options list as happens when I leave the static HTML in my page.  Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: `<s:select...` is server-side code. jQuery can't possibly predict that it should make a round-trip to the server.

Comment: Ok,  so do I need to replace the s:select tag and create the Options HTML myself after I make a call to the server to get the actual options?  Just want to check if that would be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Exactly that. You'll either need to have the server regenerate the html, or generate it yourself. I'm not familiar with the server-side language you are using, otherwise I would post more of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible for client-side JavaScript to add server-side code to a page. What you need to do is create both blocks of HTML server-side and hide one of them.

JSP isn't my area, but this might work. JSP/HTML:

```
<div id="definitionsDiv">
    <s:select id="typeDropdown" list="types" listKey="id" listValue="value" value="3" onchange="getWordList()"/>        
</div>
<div id="definitionsDiv2" style="display:none">
  <s:select id="typeDropdown" onchange="getWordList()" value="1" listvalue="value"     listkey="id" list="types"></s:select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function buildDefinitionsHTML() {
    $("#definitionsDiv").empty().append($('#definitionsDiv2').children()); 
}
```

Using `.append()` in this way will move the existing DOM elements from the hidden DIV into the desired target DIV.

However, using `display:none` only hides the second DIV from the page; it doesn't remove it. Therefore, you may want to move `definitionsDiv2` outside of your `<form>` tags so it doesn't get submitted invisibly along with `definitionsDiv`.